# Radius of Convergence When Coefficients form a Convergent Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I have the power $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ for which $a_n \rightarrow a \neq 0$, and am asked to conclude that the radius of convergence is equal to or smaller than $1$.

I tried using the following fact, but couldn't see its utility:

> $\lim \sup x_n = \ell \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \ge N$ we have $x_n > \ell - \epsilon$, and that there exist finitely many terms for which $x_n > \ell + \epsilon$.

I have tried proving the contrapositive as well as doing a proof by contradiction, but I cannot see the way. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the radius of convergence is greater than $1$ then taking $z=1$ shows that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, but this is impossible because $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a\neq 0$.

Comment: I am sorry if I am being dull, but that is a little too brief for me. Why can't $\sum a_n$ converging and $\lim a_n = a \neq 0$ be simultaneously true?

Comment: Are you familiar with the limit test? If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then necessarily $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Comment: No, but it is intuitively clear. So, I don't think I am allowed to use this.

Comment: Try proving it: it's an immediate consequence of the Cauchy criterion for series.

Comment: Ah...so clever...Damn those one line proofs! You are right; the limit test does follow very easily.Thank you very much!